# robot arm control with ros/arduino

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started ROS, I wonder if ROS with Arduino could control my robot arm and solve kinematics and inverse kinematic equations in real-time run? Does anyone have a similar experience?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394888/robot-arm-control-with-ros/arduino/) by [Mahmoud_shaban](https://answers.ros.org/users/94640/mahmoud_shaban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @mahmoud_shaban

Yes it is possible to use ROS with Arduino to control robot arms. There are very good examples how to apply Forward and Inverse Kinematics.

is it real time? From an industrial controls point of view it's not. However, you wouldn't use Arduino in those settings in general.

Take a look at this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-XXnPHYhxs
with the repo: https://github.com/bandasaikrishna/3-DOF_Manipulator

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0